# Different language for Mac OS and AppStore's softwares

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, internationalization

My OS X (Mountain Lion) is in English, and I want to keep it like this.

But, for some softwares in the *AppStore* (not necessary all), I would like to turn it in French when supported (like *OmniFocus*) because all my colleagues are working in French, and it's hard for me to tell them what to do when they have a problem:

The translator of the software does not necessarily use the same words as me, and it become difficult to navigate through the menus in some cases.

So, is it possible to configure just some software (or all of them as a last resort) to use a different language that the one used by the Mac OS?

Answer (score 4):

Yes! You can launch a single app into any other language with this nifty tool: [Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/). I use this all the time when I need english error messages for writing questions on stackexchange.com etc.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this idea, but I don't like install this kind of closed source / unsigned software… How do it proceed? I'm able to put my hand in the `plist` and other if necessary!

Comment: Hello Pascal, what exactly is your concern with, as you say, **"closed source / unsigned software"** to temporarily switch an app’s language?

Comment: How can I know that this software contains no malicious code or rootkit?

Comment: Lots of people have used it and nobody has voiced concerns or reported danger regarding this application. If this does not satisfy you, why not [ask this new question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: I took the time to [ask this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/62059/26522) myself, because I find it interesting, too.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't take that long to just change the language in System Preferences and reopen applications.

[image]

[Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/) allows temporarily changing the language of single applications.

[image]

Comment: I really don't want to switch the system locals…